# android rotate animation image loses quality

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a image rotation animation in my app. on Android 6, I don't have pixelated edges image, but on Android 9, I can see them. Please tell me what this problem may be related to?
[image: pixelazied image]

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
```

XML:

```
<rotate
    android:duration="400"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:toDegrees="6" />
```

I tried setting an anti-alias to ImageView, but it didn't help

```
android:antialias="true"
```

Comment: @Nikitic can you try by setting a scaletype

Answer (score 0):

use glide library to display the image and then add the rotation.
check Glide Library documentation or check this channel: "Master Coding" to learn more about glide